# HttpClient socket exception

Tags: sockets, .net-core, network-programming, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call some external API hosted on azure from my web Api. The API is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy it IIS on server it starts throwing System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060).A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. Although I have increased the request timeout to 5 minutes but connection is silently stopping after 21 seconds and throwing aforementioned exception.

Here is my code:

```
var telemetries = new TelemetryResponse();
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Lynx");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync("vehicletelemetries/All?key=iLJIbAVXOnpKz5xyF0zV44yepu5OVfmZFhkHM7x");

        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            telemetries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TelemetryResponse>(content);
        }
```

Exception I am getting is:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: `connected host has failed to respond` The *other server* took too long to respond. You can't do anything about this, unless it's caused by a network problem. You can't fix that through code. Can you connect to that remote server in the first place? Have you tried using `curl that_url` to see if the remote server responds?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I am calling the external API url from browser it is responding with data.

Comment: Have you tried that *from the server* ? Your development or user machines may have access to the remote service while the web server machine does not. Or your browser may be using a proxy.

Comment: Yes, it is responding when I am calling it from browser at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys the culprit was the proxy and we have to configure our HttpClient with proxy while creating it/registering in the DI container. I have registered the HttpClient in DI like this.

```
var proxySettings = new ProxySetting();
    Configuration.Bind(nameof(ProxySetting), proxySettings);

    services.AddHttpClient("Lynx", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("LynxUrl").Value);
    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = new MyProxy(proxySettings)});
```

And my proxy code is

```
public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
{
private readonly ProxySetting _proxySetting;

public MyProxy(ProxySetting proxySetting)
{
    _proxySetting = proxySetting;
}
public ICredentials Credentials
{
    //get { return new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); }
      get { return new NetworkCredential(_proxySetting.UserName, _proxySetting.Password,_proxySetting.Domain); }
      set { }
}

public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
{
    return new Uri(_proxySetting.ProxyUrl);
}

public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
{
    return false;
}
```

}

It has resolved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error code:

WSAETIMEDOUT
10060

Connection timed out.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2#WSAETIMEDOUT

Check your network connection, ip adress, port and maybe the connection got blocked from a firewall.

Comment: When I am calling external link from browser It is responding with data.

Comment: Make sure, you use the exact same URL from your program (maybe debug it).
Check Windows Defender. Maybe your program is blocked. Maybe you have some other software-firewall which blocks your program. With this error code, it is clear, that it must be a network failure.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Was my answer useful to you? Please feel comfortable to post your solution. This will help others with similar problems. Or do you need further help?

Comment: Yes, I have solved my problem. Actually there was a proxy setup by our organization which was stopping the IIS to call external url from inside the web api. When I turned off the proxy and get the direct internet access, everything was working fine.